# Footnote numbering starts at 2

Tags: footnotes, author-number, lncs

I have a `Springer` llncs.cls template. I used the `\inst` directive in the authors institutions which looks like a `footnote`. The problem is that the `footnote` now starts at number 3 and not 1.

[image]

The script:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{llncs}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{A\inst{1}\inst{2} \and B\inst{1}}
\institute{Inst. A
\and Inst B \\
\email{\{one $|$ two\}@abc.com} \\
\email{one@abc.com}
}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}\label{introduction}
A\footnote{footnote here}. \par

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the desired behavior, according to the code in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, of course, update the footnote number to `0` just after `\maketitle` so it will restart the numbering. Here's a way to achieve that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\title{Title}
\author{A\inst{1}\inst{,2} \and B\inst{1}}
\institute{Inst. A
  \email{\string{one,two\string}@abc.com} \\
  \and Inst B \\
  \email{one@abc.com}
}

\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\oldmaketitle\setcounter{footnote}{0}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
A\footnote{footnote here}.

\end{document}
```

To avoid confusion though, I'd set the institution scripts and `\footnote`s using different number scheme/symbol. Below I've changed the institution counter representation to use a symbol, while keeping the rest of the `\footnote` numbering arabic:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\title{Title}
\author{A\inst{\star}\inst{,\dagger} \and B\inst{\star}}
\institute{Inst. A
  \email{\string{one,two\string}@abc.com} \\
  \and Inst B \\
  \email{one@abc.com}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myfnsymbol}[1]{\ifcase#1
    \or\star% 1
    \or\dagger% 2
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\the@inst}{\myfnsymbol{\value{@inst}}}
\makeatother
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\oldmaketitle\setcounter{footnote}{0}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
A\footnote{footnote here}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

By adding `\setcounter{footnote}{0}` after `\maketitle`.

Comment: It would be good to add a little more detail. Ideally, you should post a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), especially since one is given in the question. This said, your answer is a less sophisticated version of Werner's answer, which appeared 40 minutes before yours, so perhaps you should just delete it as it is poor form to answer your own question with some one else's answer...

Comment: No problem. I will accept Werner's answer but might leave this as well. I personally would appreciate short answers that gets to the point. Although I appreciate it, I found Werner's answer complicating the matter.